# Sabayon LXDE - SSL problems

Tags: firefox, chrome

I am new to linux.

I have reinstated an old Pentium M 512mb RAM / 80GB HDD laptop using Sabayon LXDE

Everything has been fully installed and updated now. However, while using chronium/firefox to browse the web, every single website using HTTPS protocol is prompting the browser with certificate issues. I can type "proceed" to ignore this, but it's becoming a pain.

Is there something I need to do in order to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I was being a little stupid here. My system clock thought it was 1970 so the SSL certs and dates were confusing everything.

Problem was resolved like this:

login as root in the terminal and type the following two lines:

```
sudo ntpdate pool.ntp.org
sudo hwclock --systohc
```

Thanks to TAFKA 'goldilicks for your additional help. I would vote you up but am too low ranking.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have a directory, `/etc/ssl/certs`.  You should.  It may be a symlink, but in any case, there should be at least one file in it, and when you open that up it should start something like this:

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIDzzCCAregAwIBAgIDAWweMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBBQUAMIGNMQswCQYDVQQGEwJB
VDFIMEYGA1UECgw/QS1UcnVzdCBHZXMuIGYuIFNpY2hlcmhlaXRzc3lzdGVtZSBp
```

If not, you need to install this.  I am not familiar with "entropy", the sabayon manager, but you should be able to search available repositories for a package that provides something starting with the path `/etc/ssl/certs`.

---

If there are certificates there, have a look in:

- Firefox: *Edit->Preferences->Advanced->Certificate Manager->Authorities*
- Chrome: *Settings->Advanced->HTTPS/SSL->Certificates->Authorities*

Note the "Authorities" at the end.  That's what you want to add stuff to, not "Servers".  If there's nothing there right now, that's the source of your problem.  If there is, something weirder may be going on, but it doesn't hurt to try.

Select "Import" and navigate to `/etc/ssl/certs`.  It should pick up on the `.crt` files there.  Add all of them and see if this helps.

You should end up with dozens of authorities listed, and these should include, e.g., *VeriSign, Inc* and *GlobalSign*.  If not, your certs list is abbreviated in some wacky way.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I do have that directory. It has files in it. On return to websites such as google.com it's remembered that I said to proceed. But not tried to see if these certs are retained on reboot yet.

Comment: Okay, I've added a last couple paragraphs about adding certs to each browser specifically.

Comment: Fantastic. I will be sure to check that out when back go the computer later. I think you are more thank likely pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: Hmm..there are entries in that certs directory. I tried to do as you suggested, but the import facility is on a one by one basis rather than select all. I tried one, but it prompted me with viewing the file rather than importing it. Perhaps it was already in the certs directory?